# jQuery cookie scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery and cookie.jquery to remember the scroll position. Is there anything I can do to improve my code? Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // convert cokkie variable for easy access
    var prev_scroll_position = $.cookie('prev_scroll_position');

    // scroll to position
    $(window).scrollTop(prev_scroll_position);

    // update cookie when user scrolls
    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
        var scroll_positon = $(window).scrollTop();
        $.cookie('prev_scroll_position', scroll_positon, { expires: 7, path: '/' });
    });

});
```

Comment: You could use a `debounce` function, so the scroll function wont be called for every pixel, but after scrolling has stopped for Xms - http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function. This will prevent the scroll-function to be a bottleneck while scrolling

Comment: I have created a example here: http://jsfiddle.net/6x8kkjhu/

Answer (score 2):

@EthanBierlein Made a really good point, but he forgot something important.

It's **always** a good idea to wrap your code on an anonymous function:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        [code]
    });
})(window.jQuery);
```

This prevents problems in case you run `jQuery.noConflict()` before, but you forget it.

---

You have the following code block:

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll_positon = $(window).scrollTop();
    $.cookie('prev_scroll_position', scroll_positon, { expires: 7, path: '/' });
});
```

Instead of this, consider wrapping the `$.cookie` call in a `setTimeout`:

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll_positon = $(window).scrollTop();
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.cookie('prev_scroll_position', scroll_positon, { expires: 7, path: '/' });
    }, 10);
});
```

This won't block the `scroll` event, which **may** improve UI responsiveness.

Why is that? The `scroll` event may be triggered multiple times a second, and that `setTimeout` schedules the cookie writting to a time that the browser is free.

Or that has some time for writing the cookie.

You should experiment with it.

---

### Update!

As [@Pevara](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/42135/pevara) pointed out in the comment section, this is not 100% a good idea.

He suggests to use a `clearTimeout`. From there, I could infer what he was trying to say.

Still follow the advice to use a `setTimeout`, but with a bigger delay (as he suggested: 250ms).

But now, the twist:

```
var timeout;
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll_positon = $(window).scrollTop();
    
    clearTimeout(timeout); //clear it to avoid crazy writing
    
    //and create a new interval to write it later
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        $.cookie('prev_scroll_position', scroll_positon, { expires: 7, path: '/' });
    }, 250);
});
```

This will eliminate all the craziness of writing cookies like mad! And will write it only once, saving the browser from re-re-re-re-writing it.

Comment: While I basically agree with your answer, and believe a debounce function should definitely be used here, yours is missing a (critical!) `clearTimeout` as far as I can tell. Not much debouncing going on here, just a little delay before you start writing cookies like crazy. Also 10ms is hardly a delay... I would at least go for 250ms here

Comment: @Pevara I see what you mean with the `clearTimeout`. That would be a great idea! Only write the cookie if you want `n` milliseconds. That really is amazing! I will look into it in 10 minutes (I'm eating now)

Comment: @Pevara Fixed it! Hope it is what you meant (or better).

Comment: Much better! Not something I invented btw, it's a well known technique called Debouncing, it is even build right into popular js toolboxes like underscore.js

Comment: @Pevara I had no idea of the name, but at the time I didn't remembered of it. I know it is quite used and I've used it myself a few times before. Thank you for the reminder. I'm sure I can use it somewhere again.

Answer (score 0):

There's really not much to improve here. The only thing I'd recommend would be to remove `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`. See this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643990/is-document-ready-necessary) for more detail.